# Are there any issues with settings when upgrading from PHP 5.1.2 to 5.3.8?

Tags: php

I have never upgraded my version of PHP but feel I need to to use some of the new abilities. So I was wondering if there is any risk of losing my settings or even perhaps breaking the functionality of my code when upgrading?

Comment: Yes, there is. Anyway too vague without any code. Consult the manual instead http://php.net/manual/en/migration52.php and http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a section available on the PHP website that [feature changes between versions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration52.php), including any backwards incompatible features.
You'll likely have to check the 5.1->5.2 and the 5.2->5.3 pages on the left navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The biggest problems I've seen is with old code that uses assignment by reference functions

```
$sFoo =& $sBar;
```

99% of the time you can change the code to

```
$sFoo = $sBar;
```

and it works great--Your mileage may vary

Also 5.2 defaults to having the short_open_tag being off. if your code all begins with `<?php` instead of just `<?` I suggest keeping this off to promote good programming, if not you'll need to change it (recommended) or change the short_open_tag to on in your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The best way to find out is to deploy your application in a test environment with the new version of PHP and thoroughly test it before upgrading PHP on your production server.